# How to put my bot's token in an external file

Tags: discord.js

I want create a bot and have a question:

Is it possible to put my bot's token in a text file, import it and then write something like `client.login(myFile)`?

Answer (score 3):

You could set your bot's token into a `.env` file, thanks to the **dotenv** npm module just like this:

`TOKEN=YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE`

And then, into your `index.js`:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
const token = process.env.TOKEN;

Client.login(token);
```

More information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: I tested put token in a console.log and the debug console return 'undefined'

Comment: You have to install the dotenv npm module before doing anything - ```npm install dotenv```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using .env files as Mazz said because they're a lot safer but another alternative is just a regular .json file.

**Bot.js:**

```js
const config = require('./config.json');
Client.login(config.token);
```

**Config.json:**

```
{
    "token": "YOUR-BOT-TOKEN"
}
```

Comment: I tested put token in a console.log and the debug console return{token: 'MY_TOKEN'}

Comment: I'm glad it works - however it isn't as safe as my answer

Comment: If you are pushing code into your github, make sure you add `/config.json` as a new line to your .gitignore file. You don't want to make your bot's token publicly available.